# How accurate was the depiction of the Japanese Canadian community in the movie Vancouver Asahi?

Tags: japan, social-history, education, canada, interwar

In the movie "Vancouver Asahi", it is shown that

- Japanese Canadians in Vancouver lived in their ethnic neighborhood and did not mingle with white Canadians at work.
- second generation "Nisei" people did not go to college and were restricted to blue collar jobs, and they were paid about half the salaries as white Canadians.
- the community was excluded from college scholarships. Didn't Canada subsidise college education in that era? Was this community excluded from the subsidized fees as well?

Could someone verify if the above depiction in the movie is accurate, and also answer my question about the college fees?

Comment: `Didn't Canada subsidise college education in that era?` They were also very racist in that era.